# PSA for CiviCRM vulnerability released 7/18/18?

Tags: security-advisory

I've received an notice from our Civi support saying that 
"The CiviCRM Security team has issued a Public Security Advisory regarding a security vulnerability.  The fixes to this vulnerability will be released to the public on July 18th."

I was interested in getting some background, but I can't find the PSA. Can someone please point me toward it? Or is Civi just supplying that info to certain people in advance of the PSA being released on 7/18? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this question now - you can find the [seven advisories here](https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/announcing-civicrm-531-and-4638-security-release).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was an advanced notice - the release is due out 18 July 13:00 - 16:00 EST (best current estimate)